# I am trying to find OEM USB drivers for my FNAC 5 HD?

Tags: android

So I am developing apps for androids and just bought a FNAC 5 HD from FNAC, but cant seem to locate any OEM-USB drivers to debug on it.
Its running JellyBeans (4.2).
Have I made a huge mistake to get a phone done my FNAC?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of USB drivers here (but I don't see FNAC, not sure what that brand is)

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

I bet you will be fine, just need to search more for your drivers (I bet they exist).

Check the manufacturers website as well, they generally post them there.

Answer (score 1):

My girlfriend also has a Fnac tablet I want to use for testing app, but i have also been unable to find a compatible USB device driver for it.

All i can find is the manufacturer: 
http://www.bqreaders.com/gb/ --English
http://www.bqreaders.com     --Spanish

But they are not listed on the oem-usb page

Hope that helps a little, if you find a solution i'd love to hear it :)

Comment: It seems the USB-port I was trying to use wasnt working properly, because after activating "Developer-mode" by clicking on the build-version in the "About phone"-setting, all I had to do was connect the phone and Eclipse found the phone as a debugable device. Im running Windows 7 for the record